# Firestore - Subcollections Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, collections, google-cloud-firestore

So I'm trying to learn some Firestore basic functionality and have watched "Kilo Locos" videos on YouTube explaining CRUD operations. I want to take his method of code and create subcollections from it. Basically, how can I add a collection and make the 'User' collection a sub collection from this new collection. Any help is greatly appreciated, many thanks!!

Here is a link to download the project:
https://kiloloco.com/courses/youtube/lectures/3944217

**FireStore Service**

```swift
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

class FIRFirestoreService {
    
    private init() {}
    static let shared = FIRFirestoreService()
    
    func configure() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
    
    private func reference(to collectionReference: FIRCollectionReference) -> CollectionReference {
        return Firestore.firestore().collection(collectionReference.rawValue)
    }
    
    func create<T: Encodable>(for encodableObject: T, in collectionReference: FIRCollectionReference) {
        do {
            let json = try encodableObject.toJson(excluding: ["id"])
            reference(to: collectionReference).addDocument(data: json)
            
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    func read<T: Decodable>(from collectionReference: FIRCollectionReference, returning objectType: T.Type, completion: @escaping ([T]) -> Void) {
        
        reference(to: collectionReference).addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, _) in
            
            guard let snapshot = snapshot else { return }
            
            do {
                
                var objects = [T]()
                for document in snapshot.documents {
                    let object = try document.decode(as: objectType.self)
                    objects.append(object)
                }
                
                completion(objects)
                
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func update<T: Encodable & Identifiable>(for encodableObject: T, in collectionReference: FIRCollectionReference) {
        
        do {
            
            let json = try encodableObject.toJson(excluding: ["id"])
            guard let id = encodableObject.id else { throw MyError.encodingError }
            reference(to: collectionReference).document(id).setData(json)
            
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    func delete<T: Identifiable>(_ identifiableObject: T, in collectionReference: FIRCollectionReference) {
        
        do {
            
            guard let id = identifiableObject.id else { throw MyError.encodingError }
            reference(to: collectionReference).document(id).delete()
            
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

**FIRCollectionReference**

```swift
import Foundation

enum FIRCollectionReference: String {
    case users
}
```

**User**

```swift
import Foundation

protocol Identifiable {
    var id: String? { get set }
}

struct User: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: String? = nil
    let name: String
    let details: String
    
    init(name: String, details: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.details = details
    }
}
```

**Encodable Extensions**

```swift
import Foundation

enum MyError: Error {
    case encodingError
}

extension Encodable {
    
    func toJson(excluding keys: [String] = [String]()) throws -> [String: Any] {
        
        let objectData = try JSONEncoder().encode(self)
        let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: objectData, options: [])
        guard var json = jsonObject as? [String: Any] else { throw MyError.encodingError }
        
        for key in keys {
            json[key] = nil
        }
        
        return json
        
    }
    
}
```

**Snapshot Extensions**

```swift
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore

extension DocumentSnapshot {
    
    func decode<T: Decodable>(as objectType: T.Type, includingId: Bool = true) throws  -> T {
        
        var documentJson = data()
        if includingId {
            documentJson!["id"] = documentID
        }
        
        let documentData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: documentJson!, options: [])
        let decodedObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(objectType, from: documentData)
        
        return decodedObject
    }
}
```

Comment: Add your code, not links to pictures of your code. Also, your question lacks clarity.

Comment: Hi Picciano, please see the revised question. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Firestore structure cannot have collection as children of other collections.

The answer to your question (*How can I add a collection and make the 'User' collection a sub collection from this new collection?*) is you cannot. Instead you must put a document between those two collections.

---

[Read this for more information.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#hierarchical-data)

It says: `Notice the alternating pattern of collections and documents. Your collections and documents must always follow this pattern. You cannot reference a collection in a collection or a document in a document.`

Comment: Hi AgRizzo, thank you for the reply, I was aware of this, my idea was to add an auto ID to the first collection and then to have the sub collections nested inside this auto ID? This is possible surely?

Comment: If you're aware, you should use the Firestore terms **collection** and **document** because even now you are saying *auto ID* which does not mean anything. Are you saying you will add a document to the top level collection, and then add the *user* collection under that document? If so, then **Yes**.

Comment: Sorry!! Yes that is what I was meaning, assigning an auto ID to the document of the top level collection and then having the collection ‘user’ under that document. Do you know how I can do that using the above method of code? Thank you for your help!!